# How to resolve OpenStack error No compute service record found for host

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm running a fresh install of the ocata release of OpenStack. When I try to launch an instance, it fails with a "no hosts available" error.  I see the following in /var/log/nova-scheduler.log:

2017-07-24 20:29:39.464 14400 WARNING nova.scheduler.host_manager [req-6f4ff67c-a819-4378-b9f4-fb66c720513b 9879cf1dc8954d5a9606fb555beed1fb f2d743585bd84323959131e1aabd885b - - -] No compute service record found for host ip-10-0-0-\
180
2017-07-24 20:29:39.464 14400 WARNING nova.scheduler.host_manager [req-6f4ff67c-a819-4378-b9f4-fb66c720513b 9879cf1dc8954d5a9606fb555beed1fb f2d743585bd84323959131e1aabd885b - - -] No compute service record found for host ip-10-0-0-\
78
2017-07-24 20:29:39.465 14400 INFO nova.filters [req-6f4ff67c-a819-4378-b9f4-fb66c720513b 9879cf1dc8954d5a9606fb555beed1fb f2d743585bd84323959131e1aabd885b - - -] Filter RetryFilter returned 0 hosts
2017-07-24 20:29:39.465 14400 INFO nova.filters [req-6f4ff67c-a819-4378-b9f4-fb66c720513b 9879cf1dc8954d5a9606fb555beed1fb f2d743585bd84323959131e1aabd885b - - -] Filtering removed all hosts for the request with instance ID 'ba62693\
3-5a3c-4661-ace4-ce8b59cc5505'. Filter results: ['RetryFilter: (start: 0, end: 0)']

I do have two compute hosts, and their FQDN's are ip-10-0-0-180.eu-central-1.compute.internal and ip-10-0-0-78.eu-central-1.compute.internal.  Where is nova finding the hostname "ip-10-0-0-180"?  I've looked in the nova and nova_api databases (I've used mysqldump to dump them) and nowhere (anymore) do any records with just ip-10-0-0-180 (or ip-10-0-0-78) exist.  Why is nova-scheduler trying to find a "service record" for this hostname?

In any case, I've been unable to launch even one instance as all requests fail with "Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available."

Comment: Can you check the outputs of "nova host-list" and "nova hypervisor-list" ?

Comment: The issue turned out to be this: the compute and controllers hostnames were FQDNs (in /etc/hostname and `hostname`). This, apparently, is not allowed and messes up Nova. I changed the hostnames, deleted the various nova databases, and resync'ed the databases. Now I'm able to start instances.